# html pop up panel open with java script working loacal host but not working at server side

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins

i am using html with java script open panel at page load and close properly at local server but when i am using this code at server side open panel at page load but not close panel at server side...how to solver this problem.....code working local host but not working at server side help me

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Simple Slide Panel</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".btn-slide").click(function () {
$("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
$(this).toggleClass("active");
return false;
});
$(".btn-slide").trigger('click');
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body 
{
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width: 570px;
font: 75%/120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a:focus
{
outline: none;
}
#panel 
{
background: #754c24;
height: 200px;
display: none;
}
.slide
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-top: solid 4px #422410;
background: url(images/btn-slide.gif) no-repeat center top;
}
.btn-slide
{
background: url(images/white-arrow.gif) no-repeat right -50px -50px;
text-align: center;
width: 144px;
height: 31px;
padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
font: bold 120%/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
.active {
background-position: right 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="panel">
<!-- you can put content here -->
</div>
<p class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide">Slide Panel</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you give a link to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check whether the jquery library is getting included in page.in firebug you can find it.
if its not getting included try prepending './' to the src

i.e src="./jquery.js"

Answer (score 1):

Bhaiya ka ho ka raha hai hiyan..susra gande gande question puch rahe ho ....  try prepending './' to the src

i.e src="./jquery.js"  this will help u a gr8 deal